# VNEXT Unable to build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, dnx, dnvm

So the issue is, during building my VNEXT Web app, i get following errors:

Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   OHL.Web.DNX Core 5.0
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  OHL.Web.DNX Core 5.0

plus 760 other errors (basic language level). It seems to have lost every relation to the dnx building foundation.

How do i fix this? i have tried switching dnvm to beta 5 and back to 4, nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Seems you are missing a reference.  Open your project.json and make sure you don't require a different reference for dnx451 as you would for dnxcore5.   Example; for using `XDocument`, I had to add a reference for dnx451 as `System.Xml.Linq` and in dnxcore50 I had to add `System.Xml.XDocument`.   I'm not saying you are using `XDocument` but this type of scenario is common for other APIs like `HttpClient`, etc..

Comment: even with everything commented out i still get errors, that doesnt even list the error location in code.

dependencies removed aswell

Comment: Rebuilding can build it, building normally fails.

Comment: Turns out somehow using beta5 packages breaks everything. Why, i have no idea

Comment: It is a reference issue.  I know it doesn't seem like it but it is.  Even if you have your projects selected to use 5, it still requires 4.5 be set up with the correct references.  You can use the beta packages but must make sure that they will work with 4.5, if not, then you have to find the package that will work for 4.5 and add that reference.  Change your project to use 4.5 and recompile.  It may lead you to the missing reference.

Comment: Fixed everything now ^^

Comment: Would you care to share your experience to help others in the future?